# Sending emails from ec2 using SES and SwiftMailer

Tags: php, email, amazon-ec2, swiftmailer, amazon-ses

I have up and running my ec2 instance on a `California` node Everything is working except my simple contact.php form.

I have read alot about ec2 being really hard to send emails from. And it is, nothing seems to be working"

I have thus stumbled upon SiftMailer and installed it on the ec2 instance running Amazon's linux using `yum install php-swift-Swift.noarch`

I have also set up the ses credentials on the Oregon cluster (because they don't have a mailer on the California one)

Now for the code Very Simple:

```
<?php
    require '/usr/share/pear/Swift/swift_required.php';
    $transport = new Swift_SmtpTransport(
      'email-smtp.us-west-2.amazonaws.com', 465, 'ssl', 'KEY' ,'SECRET'  );
 // $transport->setUserName('')


  //Create the Mailer using your created Transport
 $mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);

  //Create the message
 $message = Swift_Message::newInstance();
 $message->setSubject("What up?");
 $message->setFrom(array('mygmail@gmail.com'));
 $message->setTo(array('mygmail@gmail.com'));
 $message->setBody("
     <p>
     Dude, I'm <b>totally</b> sending you email via AWS.
     </p>
     ", 'text/html');

$mailer->send( $message );

 ?>
```

Now the error that I get is

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Swift_TransportException' with message 'Expected response 
code 250 but got code "530", with message "530 Authentication required "' in 
/usr/share/pear/Swift/Swift/Transport/AbstractSmtpTransport.php:386 Stack trace: #0 
/usr/share/pear/Swift/Swift/Transport/AbstractSmtpTransport.php(281): 
Swift_Transport_AbstractSmtpTransport->_assertResponseCode('530 Authenticat...', Array) #1 
/usr/share/pear/Swift/Swift/Transport/EsmtpTransport.php(245): 
Swift_Transport_AbstractSmtpTransport->executeCommand('MAIL FROM: executeCommand('MAIL 
FROM: _doMailFromCommand('mygmail@gmail...') #4 
/usr/share/pear/Swift/Swift/Transport/AbstractSmtpTransport.php(444): 
Swift_Transport_AbstractSmtpTransport->_doMailTransaction(Object(Swift_Message),
```

'mygmail@gmail...', Array, in
    /usr/share/pear/Swift/Swift/Transport/AbstractSmtpTransport.php on line 386

So 'mygmail' is my actual email i just put that in for my post. And the 'KEY' and 'Secret' are the ones I got when I created the credentials in IAM that the SES instructions told me to make.

ALSO I verified this email on SES web interface as well.

Please let me know if I need to make this more clear.

Comment: Did you figure it out?

Comment: Years later - unfortunately not.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you fixed this or not, but it might be that you incorrectly used your credentials, as you haven't specified this info here.

I would suggest to try to replace:
`'KEY'` with your email address `'mygmail@gmail.com'`
`'SECRET'` with your email address `'your_gmail_password'`

Such settings worked for me on Yii2 with Swiftmailer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need include  SMTP credentials of your AWS SES.